# is that nested methods right? why I get empty query?

Tags: php, mysql, methods, nested

I wonder why I get errors with that code? Can Someone help?
My class is to get some information from database using nested methods,suppose I get an empty query

```
<?php
class db {
 public function __construct(){
 if(mysql_connect("localhost","root","0000")){
     mysql_select_db("myblog");

 }else{
     echo mysql_error();
 }

 }

   public function select($row){
      $sql="SELECT".$row;
      return $this;
   }

   public function from($table){
      $sql.="FROM".$table;
      return $this;
   }

   public function where($condition){
     $sql.="WHERE".$condition;
      return $this;
   }

}
$ddb=new db;
$qq=$ddb->select("*")->from("news")->where("id='1'");
$query=  mysql_query($qq);
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($query)){
    echo $row->title;
}
?>
```

Comment: Add debugging to each of your methods so you know what they're returning. Echo out the finished statement so you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Your query ends up without spaces... `SELECT*FROMnewsWHEREid=1`

Comment: @rsplak, actually, mysql_query() doesn't even get string in this code.

Comment: when put an echo statement the outout is    SELECT *SELECT *FROM newsSELECT *FROM newsWHERE id=1 how can I solve this problem and get the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define __toString() special method to use your object as a string:

```
class db {

    private $sql = '';

    public function __construct() {
        if (mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "0000")) {
            mysql_select_db("myblog");
        } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }

    public function select($row) {
        $this->sql = "SELECT ".$row;
        return $this;
    }

    public function from($table) {
        $this->sql .= " FROM ".$table;
        return $this;
    }

    public function where($condition) {
        $this->sql .= " WHERE ".$condition;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->sql;
    }

}

$ddb = new db();
$qq = $ddb->select("*")->from("news")->where("id='1'");
$query = mysql_query($qq);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `$this` in each of the methods to append to `$sql`

```
   // Declare the class property
   public $sql = "";


   // And use $this->sql in the methods
   // Also note whitespace added around SELECT, FROM, WHERE
   public function select($row){
      $this->sql="SELECT ".$row;
      return $this;
   }

   public function from($table){
      $this->sql.=" FROM ".$table;
      return $this;
   }

   public function where($condition){
     $this->sql.=" WHERE ".$condition;
      return $this;
   }
```

Then when you query it, use `$ddb->sql`, since you are not returning the SQL string.

```
$ddb->select("*")->from("news")->where("id='1'");
$query = mysql_query($ddb->sql);
```

And it goes without saying that hopefully you intend to be calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` on any variables you construct into your `where()` method.  As it is, you have no particular escaping on it.

Answer (score 0):

run a var_dump on $qq

That will show you the problem instantly.

To me it looks as if you are missing a couple of spaces in your query and that you aren't returning the query string $sql but instead $this in your db class

Comment: this was usefull for me to detect error but didnt solve all the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

- use `$this->sql` instead of `$sql` in the methods `select`, `from`, `where`
- output the query like this: `$ddb->select("*")->from("news")->where("id='1'")->sql` or create a `getSQL()` method which just returns the `$sql` field and query it like `$ddb->select("*")->from("news")->where("id='1'")->getSQL()`

You should also consider creating a method which creates a `mysql_query` (not just the string) or some methods for retrieving methods, so it's easier to use.